# facebook Login integeration issue in my sample app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, facebook

In my app users can login by using facebook. I also have Facebook official app in my mobile phone and it is logged in. When I try to login from my app it asks for email and password. Is it possible to auto login if facebook app already logged in? How can I do that? because I know almost all apps use this feature

I am using openFB.js plugin for facebook login integeration both android and ios.

Comment: i'd recommend to use the graph api and follow the facebook instructions to set up single sign on for your app!

Comment: thanks for your response......Let me try..

Comment: i tried this but it not working..